# How did Euron get so close unnoticed?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Attention, heavy spoiler ahead (Season 7, episode 2).

> At the end of the Season 7, Episode 2, Euron attacked and destroyed the Targaryen fleet. My question is how did he manage to get so close to the admiral ship, where two queens had their quarters, without a little bit of notice?
>  From my understanding the admiral's ship was in the middle of their fleet. To ram them, Euron had to go through the whole Targaryen fleet and not trigger any alarms. How is that possible?

Comment: This question seems like it'd bring a primarily opinion based answer as we don't know very much about the formation of the fleet or their location. Any answer would be based purely on speculation

Comment: "From my understanding the admiral's ship was in the middle of their fleet." If you don't mind my asking, where'd you get this understanding?

Comment: When you look at the scene you can see ship all around them. It could be ennemy ship but i assumed it was friendly. But i get your point and we don't have enough information on the scene.

Comment: I've Voted to Close this question as part of our Future Works Policy

Comment: I think that was the Dornish and rebel Iron Islands fleet, not the Targaryen fleet that sailed from Easteros. (Essos? Essos.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Assuming you mean "rebel Iron Islands" fleet to mean "Yara and Theon's fleet", they **are* the Targaryen fleet. Remember that Dany's boats were burned at the beginning of the previous season and I don't remember her building new boats (which is why Dany works with Yara in the first place)

Comment: @Flater: yeah, those guys. Oh yeah I forgot Dany’s boats being burned. And of course Yara and Then did basically say cool, we’re your navy eh.

Comment: @Flater There's also the ships she took from the slavers who attacked Mereen, in S6E9 (think Tyrion's quip to the three defeated masters, about how Dany loves ships), they're the ones with black and red Targ sigil sails, presumably on route to Castely Rock carrying unsullied (whereas Yara's fleet was heading to Dorne)

Comment: @user568458: Good call on the ships, but it seems silly to travel to Casterly Rock by boat. While it is near water, [this map](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fe/d6/69/fed6694b60c7f492b9480e8a71a154d4.jpg) shows Casterly Rock on the far West, whereas Dragonstone is on the far East. Quite a long journey, _which would funnily enough still have to pass by Sunspear_. Also, the Dothraki would much prefer travelling by land, and I doubt that the Unsullied expect to have (or even want) a say in the matter.

Comment: This question is now in the reopen-queue. There's not enough information available so far to objectively answer it from the show. We don't know how did Euron plan it, where did the fleets meet, what was the order of battle of either side etc. IF we get any of that info in the future episodes, this should be reopened. if not, this is POB

Comment: @user568458: Hindsight 20/20, but in episode 3, you can see that Grey Worm's fleet also had Greyjoy sigils on their sails (at the very least a notable part of his fleet).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Euron's ships appear from the mist. It is obvious from Yara's reaction that their presence was unnoticed.
- The initial attack occurs by catapult fire. The counter tactic to catapult fire is to spread yourselves out. If you stick together, the catapult only needs to aim at the center of your group and it is liable to hit someone. It is not a precision instrument, it's unlikely to hit its intended target. Therefore, if the ships spread out (which is the best tactic), this gives Euron the opening to sail in between the spread out fleet.

> **edit** An even better point: Being bombarded by catapult fire would give Yara's ships a reason to want to sail *into the mist*. This may have been an intentional tactic by Euron.

There are also a few things to take into consideration. Though they are from the books, and the show could have diverged from the books in this regard, it has not yet been confirmed that the show has actively contradicted the books:

- Euron plays with the supernatural, he is a very lovecraftian character. It is possible that he controlled the mist, therefore managing to sneak up on the fleet, who did not consider the mist to be anything more than a natural phenomenon.
- Euron's flagship is called the Silence, as its crew are all mutes. Although I'm not sure how deep this goes in the books, it's possible that the Silence intentionally operates more quietly so as to not give away their position, thus making it capable of sneaking up on the enemy.

---

If Euron's sneak attack is very unusual, I expect the next episode to elaborate on this. Otherwise, it seems fair to assume that this is a normal (though very clever) tactic.

Comment: Sneaking up on Yara's fleet is the least of Euron's challenges. He first has to *find* her fleet in a vast ocean. Historically, ancient & medieval naval battles usually occurred around ports & near the coast, not out in the open ocean. Perhaps he used magic to do this? Maybe we'll learn more in the next episode.

Comment: @RobertF Boats tend to stick to the coast, as it is easier to navigate by sight than by maps and stars (unless the coastline takes you considerably longer, e.g. when crossing large bays). If Euron knows that Yara is going from Dragonstone to Sunspear, all he needs to do is sail from Sunspear to Dragonstone. [Looking at the map](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/fe/d6/69/fed6694b60c7f492b9480e8a71a154d4.jpg) it seems highly likely that Yara will pass close to Evenfall Hall, Rain House, and the cape east of Sunspear. That's where I'd set up ambushes, those places seem unavoidable.

Comment: A good point. But how does Euron know Yara is sailing from Dragonstone to Sunspear? Or that Yara is even at Dragonstone in the first place? Then there are problems with finding the enemy fleet in the dark.

Comment: @RobertF When the scene on the boats start (IIRC it starts with the Sand Snakes' banter), I seem to remember it starting with an overhead shot of the boats, all of which are lit by braziers. I can check this in a few hours but I'm pretty sure that was the case, thus rendering the boats visible. Also, the last we saw of Euron is that he promised a gift for Cersei, which is incredibly likely to be related to Dany (or Tyrion), hence why he is looking for them. He may have been unaware that Dany and Tyrion were elsewhere. I guess we'll find out. Regardless, Euron's intercept is at least plausible.